# Does not call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, swift2

Basically, my table is displaying properly as what I would want it to be. However, when I click on my cell, it doesn't goes into my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

The below screenshot also doesn't show any preloaded `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

[image]

My codes are as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return personList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = stockTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    myCell.textLabel?.text = personList[indexPath.row].personName
    myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = personList[indexPath.row].GetPersonDescription()

    return myCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let myCell = stockTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let selectedCell = myCell.textLabel?.text
}
```

EDIT: After researching, I realised that I've not set my UITableViewDelegate protocol. I tried to find online but can't find any solution. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: did you set tableView.delegate = self, and let your class adopt to UITableViewDelegate protocol?

Comment: @QuangHà No I didn't do both. How to set tableView.delegate = self? At viewDidload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Set the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate for your class
    class YourClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                self.YourTableName.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TotalsCell")
                // Delegate and DataSource for your TableView
                YourTableName.dataSource = self
                YourTableName.delegate = self
         }

   }
```

Comment: thanks! It solved my problem. Sorry, I'm new to swift.